React component Extends generic prop type using typescript
I am trying to extend existing props from Primereact DataTable component but I can't understand why I see this error:

Generic type 'DataTableProps' requires 1 type argument(s)

I was supposed to spread all existing props to my custom component adding custom props (for instance onFilteredItems) but from v-code error, it seems that I need to define 1 or more types. Obviously I don't want to declare all existing props, but only add my custom props definition.
My current code with error:
import React from 'react';
import { DataTable, DataTableProps } from 'primereact/datatable';
.....
interface DtWrapperProps extends DataTableProps {
  onFilteredItems?: (filteredItems: any[]) => void;
}
...

For some reasons is required to define custom type like that:
interface DtWrapperProps extends DataTableProps<T> {
  onFilteredItems?: (filteredItems: any[]) => void;
}

where T is one or more types and at the moment I don't know how to fix it easily.

DataTableProps is a generic type that requires a type parameter that is type DataTableValueArray or extends it, so if you are extending that interface you must also specify the type.
Example:
type DtWrapperProps = DataTableProps<DataTableValueArray> & {
  onFilteredItems?: (filteredItems: any[]) => void;
};

or
also make DtWrapperProps generic and default it to DataTableValueArray and pass an extended type through if necessary:
type DtWrapperProps<T extends DataTableValueArray = DataTableValueArray> =
  DataTableProps<T> & {
    onFilteredItems?: (filteredItems: any[]) => void;
  };

